# i have a simple question about file directory in html and how to show the results of a file search

Tags: html, file, directory

i have a piece of code that let's the user see find a file how do i get it to display where it is save eg desktop/folder/file.

my current code is a basic file input that goes like

```
<input type="file"/>
```

i want my page to display where the file is saved also on a side not is there a way to display search file results. I look up programing work and my page will show everything that is programing work in its name.

i have not tried anything as i am unsure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want to get the full file path of a file uploaded via an HTML input element, if not, let me know.

If so, such behavior is intentionally blocked by most browsers, except for firefox. See [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav). If you want to raed the file, you can use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) class. Alternatively, you can make an object URL to the file object, on the onchange event, simply

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

to use for reading purposes.

Comment: thank you for your comment i appreciate the help i am curious if you know how once the user uploads the file if theres a way to let them open it

Comment: @alandticdead what do you mean by "open it"? To view the contents, you can fetch the URL using fetch like `fetch(url).then(r => r.text()/*or r.blob() for binary data*/).then(r=> console.log(r));`